# How can I retrieve the conversion gclid list using CampaignId and date range?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I am using Google `Adwords api` for my project.I have list of CampaignId's in specific date range, in my db.Using this how can I retrieve conversion's `gclid` list of each CampaignId in a specific date range from Google Adwords api.